# jquery mobile problem loading listview sub pages - AMENDED CODE

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a small jquery / phonegap project that i am working on, after getting this all working as a web site i have started the process of turning it into a ajax driven phonegap project.

my list view LI items are to click through to a page i have called person.html  i was hoping to attach an id like so  person.html?id=[number]  this resulted in the error 
"error loading page"  so i have stripped it down to just go to peerson.html but i still get the error.

my file structure   is

```
EDIT - I HAVE REMOVED THE OLD REDUNDANT CODE FROM POST
```

i have now managed to get the link to go to my page via ajax, i can not see the url structure but i have it like this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="person.html?id">
```

i then have this JQUERY code

```
$('div[data-url*="person.html?id"]').live("pageshow",function(){
    var personId = getParameterByName("id",$(this).data("url"));
    console.log('person required: ' + personId);
});
```

but this whole section is not excuted at all, its like jquery will not detect the page being shown or anything so any ideas please.

```
CLEANER SOLUTION
```

all pages have normal ID's,   i then have tap code as below:

```
$('.someclass').live('tap',function(){
   var idForNextData = $(this).attr('data-id');
   var pageNeedingId = $(this).attr('data-pagename');
   if(pageNeedingId !== null) {
       $.mobile.changePage(pageNeedingId);

       switch(pageNeedingId){
          case "#testpage":  LoadTestData(idForNextData);
          break;

       }
});
```

just incase anyone needs a solution